# Avoid unwanted fields of joining class spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, postgresql-9.1

I am new to spring boot and its implementation

Coming to problem : I have to `model classes songs , movies`

where movieid belong to song class and I joined this table with movies

In the controller how to implement to exclude all the fields of the `movie` except `movieid` and `title`.

My controller class is

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api")
public class SongsController {

@Autowired
SongsRepository songsRepository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/Songs", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<List<Songs>> getSongsList(){


        return new ResponseEntity<>(songsRepository.findAll(), HttpStatus.OK);}

songs class has (id , movieid, songtitile.....)
movie class has (movieid, moviename, ..........................)
```

Does anybody implemented this library https://github.com/monitorjbl/json-view

```
@Entity
public class Songs {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long    id;
    private String songTitle;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "movieId")
    private MoviesInfo moviesInfo;
    private int year;
    private List<String> singers;
    private List<String> lyricists;
    private float length;
....}}



@Entity
public class Movies {


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long movieId;
    private String title;
    private String year;
    private String director;
    private String genre;
...}}
```

Comment: Suppose it may be helpful if you could share the `Songs` and `Movies`pojo's to see the relation.

Comment: suppose you want to exclude the other parameters you can include `@JsonIgnore` as stated in the `json-view`

Comment: if I mention @JsonIgnore that will effect my movie service. I tried mentioning ignore annotation in songs pojo and include function as mentioned in json-view I didnt get output as expected

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use spring projections. It is designed to do exactly what you are asking for.

Just have a look at the [projections docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections)

Comment: I tried projection but in this case I am not able to generate the expected json.

Comment: Why not? Can you provide more details on what you tried and what structure you exactly want?

Comment: in my songs entity I want to show only three fields movieid,name,title of the movie entity. 

Do I need to write seperate projection class songProject mentioning all the fields again.

Comment: Yes. Define an interface (not a class) and just provide the getters for the fields that you need. You can then use this in your repository class. It is very clear in the documentation

Comment: I haVE year field in movie class and song class.. How to write that one in interface